# Entity framework 4 - Base entity mapping 2 tables as base class for 2 derived entities possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I have the following scenario that is causing me problems around the mapping fragments referring to same Id columns. This is what im trying to achieve not sure its even possible! 
[image]

Essentially I want to have a common way of accessing content, and as needed a specialisation of blog and article. I have the Contents entity working with the "IsBlog" boolean discriminator hand coded into the edmx. Trouble is as soon as I try to derive article and blog I have 4 "id" columns mapped.

Ive tried using a non-boolean discriminator with no joy. I've tried multiple discriminators again with no success. I would really appreciate anyones input as to if this is even possible with EF4!

Thanks

Phil

Comment: To put the "IsBlog" in your Contents table ruins your abstraction.  Why do you need it there?  I am having issues understanding the specialization of "article".

Comment: I initially wanted all the commonalities on article and blog in one base concrete entity so i could write content handling methods. Found that doing this was painful when it came to inheriting as described above. 

So i looked at Mike Taultys blog http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2008/02/14/10182.aspx and the video here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff657841.aspx that talk about using <condition name="isblog" value="true> in to provide mapping conditions. I may well of used it incorrectly. 

Article simply contains whats in content + more properties.